# Using activerecord on a table with a colum `changed` raises error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

A legacy database has a column `changed` (containing an updated_at timestamp).

This results in an error *changed? is defined by ActiveRecord*, but only when I open its association.

I have tried to:

- override [instance_method_already_implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510875/how-can-i-use-activerecord-on-a-database-that-has-a-column-named-valid-danger)
- And to [alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014831/alias-for-column-names-in-rails) that column.
- To add custom methods using `write_attribute` and `read_attribute`.

But none of that avoids the failure.

Can a `changed` column exist? At all? I would prefer not to have to alter the table, because that means changing a lot of legacycode too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the few downsides to ActiveRecord are all the already-taken attribute names.  This is one of them, and it can be an error-prone nightmare to work around ActiveRecord's declarations.

If your database supports them, you could create a view of the table just to present different column names to ActiveRecord.

Comment: My database (MySQL) supports this and it sounds a good idea, since it solves some other problems I had too. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling partial updates in ActiveRecord in your initializer:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.partial_updates = false
```

Comment: I think that disables dirty checking but it will still have defined the changed method.

Comment: Nope :(. I tried this, but it still fails. For the record: I am using it in a rake task, so I tried both an initializer and to set this at the start of the rake task. But the error stays.