# ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have to connect to an existing database used by our freeradius server. One table has a column called attribute which I'm trying to access.

When accessing, I get his error:

```
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError 
attribute? is defined by ActiveRecord
```

I've tried to select and rename this column in my model:

```
def self.default_scope
    Radcheck.select("attribute as newattribute")
end
```

But that's not working either.

Can anyone recommend a way around this? I'd really like to rename the column in rails!

Answer (score 12):

On a similar question I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9106597/1266906

Without having to care about which attributes are reserved by ActiveRecord in Rails 3.0 just add

```
gem 'safe_attributes'
```

to your `Gemfile` and the gem will try to take care of all colliding names automatically.

As with the other answer you need to use `Radcheck[:attribute]` or `Radcheck.read_attribute :attribute` / `Radcheck.write_attribute :attribute, 'value'` to access fields with internally reserved names, but the gem ensures validations like `validates_presence_of :attribute` will work as usual.

Further details are available at https://github.com/bjones/safe_attributes

Comment: I came across the same issue with an attribute valid in my legacy database. Using "safe_attributes" did work out of the box.

Comment: Just a note for Googlers: This gem will work for pretty much any reserved word *except* for `attribute`. From the readme: "It is virtually impossible to have a column named 'attribute' in your schema when using ActiveRecord."

Comment: If using Hirb also, you might need to disable before trying to render the model columns in the console, with Hirb.disable.

Answer (score 2):

I have never run into such situation but i think this should work

```
class Radcheck < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope :select=> 'attribute as newattribute'
end
```

You should use instance method default_scope not class one

Also you have an option to use instance method, like:

```
RadCheck.read_attribute :attribute
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks - I've tried this and I still get the blasted error. Do I need to alter my controller action as well? Currently I have this: @radcheck = Radcheck.all Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution that does require a change to the external database, but it is a very minor change, and it will work with any column name even `attribute`.  No gem required.

In your external/legacy database create a view that renames the problematic column.  e.g.

```sql
CREATE VIEW radcheck_view AS (
  SELECT id, username, op, value, attribute rad_attribute 
  FROM radcheck
);
```

Here the problem column is being renamed `attribute` to `rad_attribute`.

Don't forget to grant appropriate permissions on the view. In my case it is read-only usage:

```sql
GRANT SHOW VIEW ON radius.radcheck_view TO <rails_user> IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

Then, in your rails model use the view as `table_name`

```
class RadiusRadcheck < RadiusExternal
    self.table_name = 'radcheck_view'
end
```

Comment: Given that external databases would be owned and managed by a different application, this is quite a dangerous idea, not that it would even work as the external structure should not be editable by the reading application.