# DangerousAttributeError in OmniAuth Railscast Tutorial: create is defined by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, omniauth, railscasts

I've looked at [ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718651/activerecorddangerousattributeerror) and other similar threads on SO, but they don't address the same issue.

I'm following the omniauth tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1?view=asciicast

I'm able to authenticate via oauth with Twitter and return the user's data (auth). The problem is that I'm not able to create/save it in the database (sqlite3) because of this error message.

### Error:

```
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError in AuthenticationsController#create

create is defined by ActiveRecord
Rails.root: /beta/devise-omniauth1

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

### Authentications_Controller:

```
  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"] 
    current_user.authentications.create(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid'])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
    redirect_to authentications_url
  end
```

### Models:

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :authentications

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and     :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

How do I work past this error? Googling on this site and others doesn't help me understand what's going on in order to fix it. Thanks

Comment: What columns do the user and authentication models have

Comment: authentication: user_id, provider, uid, index, create, destroy

Thanks, i updated the migration and the error is resolved after taking the last 3 columns out of the table

Comment: @XTA i have the exact same problem, in what way did you remove the last 3 columns out of the table? I'm sort of a newb =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activerecord is warning you that some of your database attribute names (create etc.) clash with the names of instance methods provided by activerecord/ruby.

Since rails would otherwise create instance methods of those names to access attributes, such a clash used to cause really weird things to happen. Thus active record raises an exception to warn you that this is happening

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this following the same RailsCast.

The tutorial says to run:

```
rails g nifty:scaffold authentication user_id:integer \
        provider:string uid:string index create destroy
```

But not having the nifty scaffold stuff on my machine, I just ran

```
rails g scaffold authentication user_id:integer \
        provider:string uid:string index create destroy
```

Which behaves differently.  Instead of creating stub 'index', 'create', and 'destroy' controller methods, it created fields in the database.

Remove them and it works fine, as mentioned previously.

Comment: I just tan into the same problem-What is the best way to go about removing those fields?

Answer (score 4):

So just to finish the question off you will need to create a migration using this command:

```
rails g migration remove_silly_authentication_fields_which_should_not_be_there
```

Which looks something like this:

```
class DropSillyControllerAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      remove_column :authentications, :index
      remove_column :authentications, :create
      remove_column :authentications, :destroy
   end
end
```

And run it using the usual:

```
rake db:migration
```

Or alternatively you should be able to run:

```
rake db:rollback
```

To roll back the changes just made to the database and:

```
rails d scaffold authentication
```

To remove all the files, then run:

```
rails g scaffold authentication user_id:integer provider:string uid:string
```

And do the other stuff manually

I did exactly the same thing myself by the way.

Comment: thanks for that! I have just ran into the same issue, although can you please clear up what exactly you put for: "rails g migration remove_silly_authentication_fields_which_should_not_be_there"

Comment: @Apane101 This should be name of the migration you created which was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Try:  current_user.authentications.create!

EDIT

So basically your problem was that you had columns in your table named the same as methods of the Modal class.

You can't have a column named create or destroy in your database.

Most likely it was a typo on your model/controller generation.

Comment: After using `current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid'])`, I still have the error: `ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError in AuthenticationsController#create create is defined by ActiveRecord`