# DangerousAttributeError in OmniAuth create is defined by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, railscasts

Please see this page, as I have the same problem: [DangerousAttributeError in OmniAuth Railscast Tutorial: create is defined by ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221273/dangerousattributeerror-in-omniauth-railscast-tutorial-create-is-defined-by-act)

However being fairly new to rails, I am not quite sure as to how to remove the fields they speak of from the database. In other-words, there is no step-by-step concise way described anywhere in that post.

The below post is in fact a proper solution, but it is unclear as to what he was referring to when he wrote: "rails g migration remove_silly_authentication_fields_which_should_not_be_there" Not sure what "silly_authentication_fields_which_should_not_be_there" is exactly.

Here is the post I am referring to:

> So just to finish the question off you will need to create a migration
>   using this command:
>
> rails g migration
>   remove_silly_authentication_fields_which_should_not_be_there
>
> Which looks something like this:
>
> class DropSillyControllerAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration    def
>   change
>         remove_column :authentications, :index
>         remove_column :authentications, :create
>         remove_column :authentications, :destroy    end end
>
> And run it using the usual:
>
> rake db:migration
>
> Or alternatively you should be able to run:
>
> rake db:rollback
>
> To roll back the changes just made to the database and:
>
> rails d scaffold authentication
>
> To remove all the files, then run:
>
> rails g scaffold authentication user_id:integer provider:string
>   uid:string
>
> And do the other stuff manually
>
> I did exactly the same thing myself by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's telling you to create a migration to remove the problematic fields and then run the migration

to make it clearer:

run this command:

```
rails g migration drop_silly_controller_attributes
```

that command will create a file in /db/migratie/ with the timestamp and that name, something like:

```
2013121212312312_drop_silly_controller_attributes.rb
```

open that file and modify it to look like this:

```
class DropSillyControllerAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :authentications, :index
    remove_column :authentications, :create
    remove_column :authentications, :destroy
  end
end
```

then you can run the migration doing:

```
rake db:migrate
```

it's confusing because the if you generate the migration with "remove_silly_authentication_fields_which_should_not_be_there" the class should be RemoveSillyAuthenticationFieldsWhichShouldNotBeThere, but then it says "DropSillyControllerAttributes", so you should generate the migration with drop_silly_controller_attributes to make it consistence