# What means this error ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Any Ideas what means this error ?

```
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError (delay is defined by ActiveRecord):
app/models/issue.rb:849:in `relations'
app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:118:in `show'
```

Thanks

Comment: It might be `sidekiq` gem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have `delay` column in `Issue` model. You should rename it, because this name is used internally by `ActiveRecord`.

Answer (score 4):

Dude, are you using the `sidekiq` gem? Sidekiq uses a method called "delay" which is causing this problem. Removing the sidekiq gem will solve your issue, OR,

Just put this in your `Gemfile`:

```
    gem 'safe_attributes'
```

and do `bundle install`

More info: [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions) and solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718651/activerecorddangerousattributeerror)

UPDATE: Alternatively, you could also install the [redmine_sidekiq](https://github.com/ogom/redmine_sidekiq/) plugin which also solves the problem.

UPDATE-2: Have created a fork of sidekiq gem which solves the problem. Kindly find it [here](https://github.com/devaroop/sidekiq). Follow the instructions in the [pull request](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/pull/1674).

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DangerousAttributeError.html), this error is "raised when attribute has a name reserved by Active Record (when attribute has name of one of Active Record instance methods)."

So basically the attribute `delay` is one that is reserved by ActiveRecord and it would be a good idea to call it something else, or you will run into naming conflicts.

Comment: Thanks omnikron, but i'am using redmine and i'cant rename this attribute, can i have any other solution do resolve this conflict.

Comment: can you show the relevant code in `app/models/issue.rb:849`?

Comment: @relations ||= (relations_from + relations_to).sort and the attribute delay is in the table relations_issues

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't really help to diagnose the problem, but you could try using the gem mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510875/how-can-i-use-activerecord-on-a-database-that-has-a-column-named-valid-dange/9106597#9106597) on a similar question.