# ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: frozen? is defined by Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am migrating an App from PHP to Rails and I have a table with a column called frozen.

Rails i throwing an error:

```
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: frozen? is defined by Active Record. Check to make sure that you don't have an attribute or method with the same name.
```

Is there a way to go around this? I can not rename the column in my table right now.

Also i tried some of the solutions in Stackoverflow and none of those work in rails 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718651/activerecorddangerousattributeerror)

Comment: I actually tried that before submitting and it does not work in Rails 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by using this code inside the model

```
def self.instance_method_already_implemented?(method_name)
  return true if method_name == 'frozen'
  return true if method_name == 'frozen?'
  super
end
```

Comment: `return true if %w(frozen frozen?).include? method_name super` would be shorter :)