# Setting column mapping in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to access legacy database that has a column named `hash` in it and ActiveRecord crashes with `ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: hash is defined by Active Record`. Any way to somehow set a name for the attribute (`alias_attribute` won't work obviously)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use ActiveRecord on a database that has a column named 'valid'? (DangerousAttributeError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510875/how-can-i-use-activerecord-on-a-database-that-has-a-column-named-valid-dange)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a new migration file to rename the old column, so you can use the correct name you want.

```
def self.up
  rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
end
```